# Why is the same SQL query with different foreign key in WHERE clause getting different performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Why are these two queries with the only difference being the campaign_id (a foreign key to another table) getting different performance and different EXPLAIN results?

Query 1 - Avg time: 0.21s

```
SELECT tx_time, campaign_id, tx_amount, tx_status FROM tx WHERE
 campaign_id=6963 ORDER BY tx_time DESC LIMIT 2500;
```

Query 2 - Avg time: 0.29s

```
 SELECT tx_time, campaign_id, tx_amount, tx_status FROM tx WHERE
 campaign_id=6946 ORDER BY tx_time DESC LIMIT 2500;
```

Query 1 vs Query 2 EXPLAIN:

```
 id  select_type   table   partitions  type    possible_keys     key             key_len   ref   rows    filtered  Extra
 1   SIMPLE        tx      NULL        index   tx_campaign_id    tx_time         4         NULL  85591   2.92      Using where
 1   SIMPLE        tx      NULL        ref     tx_campaign_id    tx_campaign_id  4         const 106312  100       Using index condition; Using filesort
```

**UPDATE:** After adding (tx_id,tx_time,campaign_id) and (tx_id,tx_time) indexes and running ANALYZE, Query 1 has improved to 0.15s but Query 2 has slowed to 13s. Updated EXPLAINs:

```
 id  select_type   table   partitions  type    possible_keys     key             key_len   ref   rows    filtered  Extra
 1   SIMPLE        tx      NULL        index   tx_campaign_id    tx_time         4         NULL  75450   3.31      Using where
 1   SIMPLE        tx      NULL        ref     tx_campaign_id    tx_campaign_id  4         const 117400  100.00    Using index condition; Using filesort
```

Table tx:

> CREATE TABLE `tx` (
>     `tx_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `tx_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>     `campaign_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>     `tx_amount` decimal(12,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
>     `tx_geo` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
>     `tx_langauge` varchar(511) NOT NULL,
>     `tx_ua` varchar(511) NOT NULL,
>     `tx_ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
>     `tx_status` tinyint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`tx_id`),
>     KEY `tx_campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
>     KEY `tx_time` (`tx_time`) USING BTREE,
>     KEY `tx_amount` (`tx_amount`) USING BTREE,
>     KEY `tx_time_campaign_id` (`tx_id`,`tx_time`,`campaign_id`) USING BTREE,
>     KEY `tx_id_time` (`tx_id`,`tx_time`) USING BTREE,
>   CONSTRAINT `campaign_idcampaign_id` FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_id`) REFERENCES `campaign` (`campaign_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10855433 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Probably because the statistics tell the query optimizer to use different indexes

Comment: @RobertKock is it because of the total possible rows 85,591 vs 106,312? Should I make any changes to optimize it further?

Comment: I'm not a DB expert. I left my comment only because I think the reason is somewhere in that direction. I leave the final answer to somebody with more expertise.

Comment: If you are worried about the 0.08s enough, you could alter your query to force the use of an index with an index hit, e.g. `SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)` ([see documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html)).

Comment: The queries show one table; the `EXPLAINs` show two tables (actually a 'self-join').  Why the discrepancy??

Comment: Yeah, those EXPLAIN reports don't seem like they are related to the queries you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `INDEX(campaign_id, tx_time)` with the columns in that order.

In general, put the `=` column first, namely `campaign_id`.  In this case, that takes care of the entire `WHERE` clause, so you can move on to the `ORDER BY`.  Then add all the columns in the `ORDER BY`, namely `tx_time`.

Having successfully built an index that handles those, *then* the processing can stop at the `LIMIT` rows and avoid a 'filesort'.

[*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Thank you! Both queries are now running at or under 0.1s. Index Cookbook is going to my favorites :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your schema, it's hard to be sure, but I'm guessing it's because the optimizer is trying to figure out which index is more useful.

I assume you don't have a compound index (transaction_id, tx_time) on the table; if you had, the optimizer would probably use that (and be faster).

If you think about how the query would work, you can either first find all the records based on transaction ID, and then sort them based on time, or you can sort the records based on time, and discard the ones that don't belong to the transaction id you care about.

The first option (find all the matching transactions, then sort them) is fastest if you have lots of transaction IDs, and not that many time stamps. 
The second is fastest if you have lots of time stamps, and not that many transaction IDs. That's why the number of rows considered varies between query plans.

The best way to optimize this is to create the compound index, and to make sure you [update the statistics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html) the query optimizer uses.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is not needed for InnoDB.  And it takes a long time for a big table.  `ANALYZE TABLE` very quickly refreshes the statistics; it, too, is rarely needed.

Comment: Yep - the question doesn't mention InnoDB, so I linked to the documentation, in the hope it would explain things, and lead to further inquiry...

Comment: @NevilleKuyt After adding the compound index, query 1 has sped up to 0.13s (from 0.21s) but query 2 has slowed down to 13s (from 0.29s). I've included the updated EXPLAINS and table schema.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt - `transaction_id`??